# What is the meaning of wizard words here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

**[SOURCE](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/a1/august-rush-script-transcript.html)** (Script of the film *August Rush*)

Wizard is trying to put a new name to his boy Evan who is already has a name.

> We're gonna need to get you a new name. Something with a little more pop.
>   I mean, in the whole world, what do you want to be? Close your eyes and
>   think about that. Found. **Doesn't have enough "yin". Little more
>   "yang", you know?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but those aren't really "wizard words." *Yin* and *yang* are Chinese terms related to [balancing forces in nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang). From the Wikipedia article on the concept:

> In Chinese philosophy, yin and yang (also yin–yang or yin yang, 陰陽 yīnyáng "dark–bright") describe how seemingly opposite or contrary forces may actually be complementary, interconnected, and interdependent in the natural world, and how they may give rise to each other as they interrelate to one another.

Whoever is speaking in your passage is appropriating the concept into folksy English, which is intended to have a somewhat humorous effect.

Comment: To be truly folksy, it must be pronounced _yin**g**'yang._